# Select attribute of next element

Tags: css

is it possible to access an attribute (selected) an element (li-2.2) in an attribute selector of a CSS selektor?

HTML

```
`<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li> <!-- should be blue because sub menu is selected-->
    <ul>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li selected>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>`
```

CSS

```
`li[selected] {
  color: red;
}}`
```

I'm looking for a CSS selektor that changes the color of the li-2-Element if li-2.1 or li-2.2 element is selected

Thank you

Comment: can you use easy word to explain ?

Comment: You are looking for this selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors in combination with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: I've tried to improove my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: `#foo + span[bar]`

But keep in mind that `bar` is not a valid attribute, maybe you want `data-bar`